# insert XML file in SQL via SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have this procedure

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[adenti] 
(
   @entra nvarchar(max)
)
as 
DECLARE @sql varchar(4000); 
SET @sql = 'INSERT INTO provaxml (arquivo) SELECT CAST(BulkColumn AS XML) FROM OPENROWSET(BULK ''' + @entra + ''', SINGLE_BLOB) as arquivo'; 
EXEC( @sql );
```

The code above works.

Is it possible to use *Integration Services* to insert all the XML file in a path into a SQL table?

Comment: Yes, it is. You can build a for each loop, make it go through all the files in a folder, store every filename in a variable, and then execute a script similar to the proc you have above, with the variable replacing the @entra variable.

Comment: If you could, please review your [open questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1483520/alejandro-carnero?tab=questions&sort=newest) Click the Up arrow on any answers that were helpful. Click the outline of the check mark to signal the question has been answered.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two different approaches you can do.

The first is as user569711 outlined and use a ForEach Enumerator and call your existing stored procedure. Advantage to this is your behaviour should be exactly as what you are currently experiencing and your testing should only need to focus on ensuring the SSIS package is picking up the right files.

The second is to use the out of the box capabilities of SSIS to deal with importing BLOB types.

## Control Flow

You will want 1 to 2 variables defined depending upon your approach. Both will be string data types. I created `SourceFolder` and `CurrentFileName`. The former defines where the files will come from and is used in either approach. The latter is used in the ForEach Loop Container to capture the "current" file.

[image: control flow]

## Data Flow

To make the data flow work, you will need to get the fully qualified list of file names added into the pipeline. Easiest way is to use a Script Transformation, acting as a source and have that add in all the files meeting your condition (*.xml).

[image: data flow]

### Foreach Loop Container

Configure as such

Collection

[image]

Variable Mappings

[image]

### Execute SQL Task

Configure thusly

[image]

[image]

### Script Source

This task will add the available files into the data flow. Minor note, this will traverse subfolders which differs from how we have the Foreach configured. It's a simple change to the third parameter (or omission) to make it top level only.

Identify your variable so it is available in the script task

[image]

Add the appropriate output columns. Your lengths may vary based on your environment.

[image]

Script here

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Wrapper;

[Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.SSISScriptComponentEntryPointAttribute]
public class ScriptMain : UserComponent
{

    public override void CreateNewOutputRows()
    {
        string fileMask = string.Empty;
        string sourceFolder = string.Empty;

        fileMask = @"*.xml";
        sourceFolder = this.Variables.SourceFolder;

        foreach (string fileName in Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder, fileMask, SearchOption.AllDirectories))
        {
            Output0Buffer.AddRow();
            Output0Buffer.FileName = fileName;
            Output0Buffer.SourceName = "Dataflow";
        }
    }
}
```

### Import Column Transformation

Configure like this

[image]

Make note of the ID here

[image]

Tie that ID back to the column with the name

[image]

### OLE DB Destination

Configure. Does not support Fast Load option.

[image]

[image]

## Reference

Nice post on using the [Import Column Transformation](http://www.bimonkey.com/2009/09/the-import-column-transformation/)

Comment: Upvoting you just for the sheer effort you take to illustrate just about anything. This is golden for inexperienced users, not only for this task but for the general knowledge and understanding of the workflow to get stuff done in SSIS.

Comment: NIce, Good!! Thanks .  I gonna try today , thanks thanks billinkc