# Import varbinary data

Tags: ssis

After we used the Export column comp.([https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12712632/export-varbinarymax-column-with-ssis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12884276/import-varbinary-data))  we want to import the flat file into the db. when i try to import the varbinary column (even to a test table with varbinary column) , an FF character are added to varbinary data (at the end ) with no reason . in order to import the file i choosed in the flat file properties the next options : unicode,unsigned the column names in the  first data row and in columns tab i added a {|}{@}{|} row delimiter in order to get one row for one column . when i run the packg. in inserts the varbinary data with FF trailing at the end off course the details are invalid . do you have any idea from where these characters appeared ?

Comment: Minor note on how the stack exchange sites work, if an answer works for you, select the check mark to indicate the question has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm misunderstanding the layout of your file (all the data is in a single file) and 1 file = 1 row in the target table. With that assumption in place, you'll want to do much as I described in this answer on [insert XML file in SQL via SSIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817099/insert-xml-file-in-sql-via-ssis)

In the section where I note "Make note of the ID here" change the data type from NTEXT to IMAGE and everything else should work the same.