# Import XML file with Bulk Insert option in SSIS package?

Tags: ssis

Is it possible to import data from XML file using Bulk Insert option in SSIS package. Without using Data Flow Task?

Answer (score 0):

The main components of an SSIS package are :

- Control Flow (Stores containers and Tasks)
- Data Flow (Source, Destination, Transformations)
- Event Handler (sending of messages, Emails)
- Package Explorer (Offers a single view for all in package)
- Parameters (User Interaction)

You will need to drag and drop the Bulk Insert task in the Control Flow.

You have two possible options :

**Solution 1 :**
Read the XML file and import the data via the `OPENROWSET` function. This function is native to T-SQL and allows us to read data from many different file types through the BULK import feature, which allows the import from lots of file types, like XML. Use a `ForEach Enumerator` and call your existing stored procedure containing the `OPENROWSET` function

**[Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817099/insert-xml-file-in-sql-via-ssis) :**

You will need 2 variables with string data types: `SourceFolder` and `CurrentFileName`.

`SourceFolder` defines where the files will come from and is used in either approach.

`CurrentFileName` is used in the ForEach Loop Container to capture the "current" file.